(No) double infinitive confusion
I've seen the phrase
Drei Bücher sollte man gelesen haben
and I wonder why here lesenis put in participle, shouldn't it be kept as infinitive according to the double infinitive rule:Drei Bücher sollte man lesen haben
?

Can you also quote what this ' double infinitive rule' says in Detail? What shall the rule have said?

@BlauKakaPOW Instagram.

@planetmaker Ersatzinfinitiv


shouldn't it be kept as infinite according to the double infinitive rule ?

There is no double infinitive, the sentence is simply in Perfekt and this is built with the Partizip Perfekt (and "haben"), "sollte" is a Modalverb here. The construction is actually just the same as in English:

One should have read three books.

Would it be in Präsens the Infinitiv would indeed be used:

Drei Bücher sollte man lesen.


The sentence (with "sollte" as its main verb) isn't Perfekt, is it? With a Perfekt like "hat/hätte lesen sollen" instead we would find ourselves in Ersatzinfinitiv territory.

"Three books one ought to have read." The variants and tenses of "sollen" are
"Drei Freunde soll man haben."  (Three friends one ought to have.)
"Drei Freunde sollt ihr sein."  (As 3 friends you'll be recognized from now on...)
"Drei Bücher soll man lesen."  (Three books one is supposed to read).
"Drei Bücher soll man gelesen haben."  (One is supposed to have read three books).
"Drei Bücher muß man gelesen haben."  (Three books are must-have-read's).
"Drei Bücher sollte man gelesen haben."
This has two slightly distinct interpretations. "sollte" could be past tense as
in the statement of your teacher: "You were supposed to/asked to have read three books..."
but also Konjunktiv II as "One would profit from having read..."
"gelesen" is just Perfekt:
"Ich habe das Buch gelesen" (I've read the book)
"Ich hatte das Buch gelesen" (I had read the book)
"Ich hätte das Buch gelesen" (I would have read the book)
"Ich las das Buch" (I read the book)
"Du hast das Buch gelesen" (you've read the book)
"Man hat das Buch gelesen" (One has read the book/ the book has been read)
"Ich werde das Buch lesen" (I'll read the book)
"Ich sollte das Buch lesen" (I'm inclined to read the book)
"Ich würde das Buch lesen" (I would read the book.)
